# Find correct location in google map using latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4.5

Using latitude and longitude I want to display the correct position by annotation. My app is showing the area, but not the correct position by annotation.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.mapView.delegate=self;
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    locatinmanager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locatinmanager setDelegate:self];

    [locatinmanager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locatinmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate methods.
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude=13.0839;
    region.center.longitude=80.2700;


    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the region for your map but not the annotation.

For blue dot you need to add annotation for the same latitude and logitude.
Add following code with yours.

```
MapPoint *mp = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:**YouReagionsCordinat** title:@"**yourLocation**"];

[mapView addAnnotation:mp];
```

If still you are stucking then go through [This tutorial](http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/)
.

Comment: where i want to add this

Comment: add it above 
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
in your code

Comment: How to set property declaration of mapPoint sir

Comment: sir how to declare MapPoint sir